# Run-time error '91' When Setting Table Listobject Cells to Worksheet Values

Tags: excel, listobject, vba

I am trying to create a sub that will store various values from a worksheet in variables and then copy the variables into the appropriate columns on a blank row in a listobject (table).  I continue to get the following error:

"Run-time error '91':
Object variable or With block variable not set"

I have tried many variations, but keep getting an error, sometimes even a different one. Any suggestions are much appreciated. This is the code

```
Sub RecordData()
    Dim strName1 As String, strName2 As String
    Dim dTimeStamp As Date
    Dim sItem1 As Single, sItem2 As Single, sItem3 As Single
    Dim sItem4 As Single
    Dim ws_1 As Worksheet, ws_2 As Worksheet
    Set ws_1 = Sheets("Data")
    Set ws_2 = Sheets("Output")


    strName1 = ws_1.Range("D1").MergeArea.Cells(1, 1).Value
    strName1 = Left(strName1, Len(strName1) - 6)
    strName2 = ws_1.Range("B17")
    dTimestamp = Now
    sItem1 = ws_1.Range("D3")
    sItem2 = ws_1.Range("E3")
    sItem3 = ws_1.Range("F3")
    sItem4 = ws_1.Range("N3")

    Dim loTable As ListObject
    Set loTable = ws_2.ListObjects("CurrentMkts")

    Dim iLastRow As Integer
    iLastRow = loTable.Range.Rows.Count
    If iLastRow = 2 Then
    Dim iTempRow As Integer
        iTempRow = iLastRow - 1
        loTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(iTempRow, 1).Value = dTimeStamp
        loTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(iTempRow, 2).Value = sItem1
        loTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(iTempRow, 3).Value = sItem2
        loTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(iTempRow, 4).Value = sItem3
        loTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(iTempRow, 6).Value = sItem4
        loTable.ListRows.Add
    Else
        iTempRow = iLastRow
        loTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(iTempRow, 1).Value = dTimeStamp
        loTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(iTempRow, 2).Value = sItem1
        loTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(iTempRow, 3).Value = sItem2
        loTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(iTempRow, 4).Value = sItem3
        loTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(iTempRow, 6).Value = sItem4
        loTable.ListRows.Add
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: what line does the code error on?

Comment: The 3rd line in the If statement - loTable.DataBodyRange.Cells(iTempRow, 1).Value = dTimeStamp

Comment: This is due to a seemingly non-sensical way blank ListObjects are handled in Excel. Move `loTable.ListRows.Add` to the line before you setting cell values. For some reason, excel sees the listobject as not having a DataBodyRange if it's blank. The 2nd part of the `IF` block should not need the `loTable.ListRows.Add` moved to the top, since actual data rows will be present.

Comment: that works. That seems to be the answer. Thank you. If you could explain a little more about the error or how non-coder like me could have best found the answer myself I would appreciate it.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman OP is right, maybe put it as answer plus a little bit more explanation :) Didn't know 'bout that too until now.

Comment: Happy to accept this as the answer

Comment: @fmc100 - I have been coding for over 20 years and I *just* came across this issue within the past year. I found it by running into it and then googling what was going on :) So, my point is, the way you found and resolved it is probably the one way it could have been found and resolved. This case is not officially documented anywhere (that I know of).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs due to a seemingly non-sensical way blank ListObjects are handled in Excel.

Essentially, in this case, because there is no data in the ListObject, Excel views the `DataBodyRange` property as non-existent, so when you try to set the values of the cells of the `DataBodyRange` the code errors.

To fix it, move `loTable.ListRows.Add` to the line before setting cell values, in the first part of the `IF` block.

The 2nd part of the IF block should not need the loTable.ListRows.Add moved to the top, since actual data rows will be present.